# JavaScript - jQuery - PHP : Display specific time dynamically in my datetimepicker from the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a jQuery datetimepicker using [xdsoft plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I want to display only specific hours/time that has been stored in my database(using php).

Example if I have values in my database:

```
'12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
'17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
```

And this is my jQuery for datetimepicker:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  formatDate:'Y/MMM/d',
  allowTimes:[
    '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', 
    '17:00', '17:05', '17:20', '19:00', '20:00'
  ],
});
```

My problem is I can't used a technique to get the time values from my database and integrate it to my jQuery. This is what I want:

```
allowTimes:[my time values in my database],
```

PLEASE HELP ME :'(

Thanks.,

Comment: then you'll need a select statement first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the datepicker in an ajax success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'gettimes.php'
}).done(function(response){
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  formatDate:'Y/MMM/d',
  allowTimes:[
     response //JSON STRING with allowed Times
   ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Problem Solved. You got it. Thanks . Love You :*

Comment: Hi, and how do you "refresh" the times everytime the user changes the month?